# For ag-grid, is it possible to access old rowData?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am creating some custom inline editing functionality and am trying to reset the data when the user hit cancel after making edits to specific columns. **I'm using `cellRenderers` for this so I don't have access to the editing params that a `cellEditor` would.**

Currently, what I am doing is saving the specific row's data in React state `originalRowInfo` when that row is clicked:

```js
const moreInfoClick = (event, toggleMoreInfo, rowData) => {
  event.persist();
  setMoreInfoLocation({ x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY });
  setRowInfo(rowData);
  setOriginalRowInfo({ ...rowData });
  toggleMoreInfo(true);
};
```

**I am getting rowData via params.data when I click on a row**

The reason I can't just use the rowInfo state is because that gets changed by ag-grid whenever I make an edit to the column. But using `{...rowData}` seems to fix that.

My only issue now is one of my column values is an array with objects inside and when I edit that column, it gets changed inside `originalRowInfo` as well. I would imagine this has something to do with object referencing.

The column looks something like this:

```js
[
  {position: 1, heat_num: 100},
  {position: 2, heat_num: 200}
]
```

And what actually gets edited is the `heat_num`

The only thing I can think of is to refetch the data from DB on Cancel but I would rather not have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `originalRowInfo` to reset to the original state if the user cancels the editing, but you may rather do the opposite: save the new value `inputValue` as temporary state when the user editing and:

- If the user submit the result: call `ICellRendererParams.setValue(inputValue)` to commit the result.
- Otherwise, if the user abort: simply discard the result by resetting `inputValue` to `ICellRendererParams.value` which is the original value.

```js
function EditableCellRenderer(params: ICellRendererParams) {
  const [editable, setEditable] = React.useState(false);
  const [originalData] = React.useState(params.value);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState(params.value);
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);
  const onEdit = () => {
    setEditable(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      inputRef.current?.focus();
    });
  };
  const onCancel = () => {
    setInputValue(originalData);
    setEditable(false);
  };
  const onSubmit = () => {
    params.setValue(inputValue);
    setEditable(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        disabled={!editable}
      />
      <button onClick={onEdit}>E</button>
      <button onClick={onCancel}>X</button>
      <button onClick={onSubmit}>S</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64081091/for-ag-grid-is-it-possible-to-access-old-rowdata]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is definitely much cleaner that my method, but I have one question. Would this work for editing multiple columns within a row at once?

Comment: You can have a look at [full row editing](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#fullRowEdit) @aus_10